# Trackpad behaves incorrectly before suspend

Tags: xorg, suspend, touchpad, xinput

I know it's a fairly common problem for trackpads to not work correctly after resuming from suspend. But, in my case the trackpad ONLY works correctly after resuming from suspend. Upon booting the machine the trackpad is awkward (e.g. scrolling is inverted, it doesn't detect 2 finger scrolling in the bottom third etc.), but after resuming from suspend it behaves correctly.

Is there a way to get this working correctly on boot? At the moment I have to suspend and resume my laptop every time I turn it on.

The machine is an HP Elitebook Folio G1 (this one specifically: https://www.technoworld.com/hp-elitebook-folio-g1-v1c43ea-abu-core-m7-6y75-8gb-240gb-ssd-12-5touch-bt-cam-win-10-pro-silver).

### Additional information

When restarting the X server the trackpad is reset to the bad state before suspending.

Looking at xinput, I've noticed that xinput --disable has no effect on the trackpad before suspending, only doing anything after resume.

So, perhaps the X server is setting the device up incorrectly, and then something to do with suspend/resume is correcting it?

I'm also seeing things in the syslog after resume along these lines: `/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3200]: (II) config/udev: Ad ding input device AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint (/dev/input/event5).`

Comment: When you suspend/resume, the Power Management subsystem runs the scripts in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` and  `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d` (see `man pm-action`). One of these scripts "fixes" your trackpad. Find it, and execute it at login.

Comment: OK, I've tried renaming those directories, so they are not run anymore and the trackpad is still fixed after suspending, so it's not any of those scripts.

But, I am seeing something in syslog along these lines: `/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3200]: (II) config/udev: Ad
ding input device AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint (/dev/input/event5)`.

Also, I've been looking at xinput, and have noticed that `xinput --disable` has no effect on the trackpad before suspending, only doing anything after resume.

Also, restarting the X server resets the trackpad to the bad state before suspending.